# OO, MVC and Observer pattern not working as expected

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

In my class, we made a simple application using MVC with the observer pattern in Java and it works. The view cannot call any methods from the model that are not included in the (Observable) interface and vice versa.

I am quite a fan of PHP and decided to make the same (simplified) example in PHP. I noticed that even though I am using an interface and passing the reference of the model as an interface, the view can still call **every** method inside the model, rendering the entire pattern useless.

Is there something I overlooked or is this not possible in PHP?

The PHP code (every reference, method, etc is the exact same as in the Java application) :

```
class App
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $model = new Model();
        $controller = new Controller($model);
    }

}

class Model implements Observable
{
    private $view;
    private $count = 1;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Model created. <br>';
    }

    public function registrate(Observer $view)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
        echo 'Model: view is registered. <br>';
    }

    public function addOne()
    {
        $this->count += 1;
        $this->view->modelChanged($this);
    }

    public function getCounter()
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return 'The view should not be able to call this method.';
    }

}

class Controller
{
    private $view;
    private $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        echo 'Controller created. <br>';
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->view = new View($this->model);
        $this->model->addOne();
    }

}

class View implements Observer
{
    public function __construct(Observable $model)
    {
        echo 'View created. <br>';
        $model->registrate($this);
    }

    public function modelChanged(Observable $model)
    {
        // Should only be able to call method "getCounter()"
        echo $model->getMessage();
    }

}

interface Observable
{
    public function registrate(Observer $view);
    public function getCounter();
}

interface Observer
{
    public function modelChanged(Observable $model);
}
```

The output, if you run this is:

> Model created.
>
> Controller created.
>
> View created.
>
> Model: view is registered.

The view should not be able to call this method. As you can see, the view can call a method of the model that is **not** declared inside the Observable interface.

How is this possible and why does this not work in PHP like it does in Java?

Comment: This question does seem better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), post it there, you're far more likely to get an extensive answer explaining possible flaws in your design, some tips and links to helpful resources

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it seems that there is something wrong with the code `The view should not be able to call this method`  The last sentence asks why it doesn't work as intended. that is off-topic on CR

Comment: @Malachi: It's not so much an issue with the code as it is a case of confusion. OP expects the interface hints to force PHP to behave in the same way as Java does. The simple fact of the matter is that PHP isn't Java, something a thorough code review would address, along with providing alternative suggestions and backing those up with documentation. It's border-line off-topic on CR, just as it is here: It's not _really_ a code-related issue, more of an _"understanding how language X differs from language Y"_ question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course the view can call every method you've defined on the model: All the methods are ***public***, which means they're callable from anywhere. Just define them as `protected` or `private` instead...

Of course, that'd limit the ways in which you can use the model in other components (such as the controller). To get around that problem, a simple fix would be to create a wrapper, which you can wrap around the model when you pass it to the view:

```
class View implements Observable
{
    public function __construct(ViewObservable $model)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
//Wrapper:
class ViewObservable
{
    /**
     * @var Model
     */
    protected $payload = null;
    public class __construct(Observable $model)
    {
        $this->payload = $model;
    }
    public function getCounter()
    {
        return $this->payload->getCounter();
    }
}
```

But really, you might want to rethink a thing or 2. It's good to use interfaces, but it doesn't make a lot of sense (to me at least) to have *all* components in an MVC architecture implement the same interface. All components have different jobs to perform, and therefore should have different interface requirements.

Comment: Then how can the controller call them?

Comment: @aaa: Answered that question by updating my answer: Your view does not have the same access rights/permissions as the controller (because its responsibilities are different), hence, the contract your `View` class enforces should be different: you shouldn't be allowed to pass `Observable` interfaces to the view just like that, the requirements should be stricter. An issue I addressed by simply strengthening the type-hints, and providing a wrapper class

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I can see that it would indeed work. However what is the point of "my" current interfaces if they can't hide any data/methods. They work exactly the same as an abstract class now, besides the fact that they can become an object.

The example I gave above, would ensure that the view can only access the methods declared in the (Observable)interface, that's how it works in Java at least. So you would say the 'only' way to do the same in PHP  is the example you gave above?

Comment: The view has the method modelChanged(Observable $model), this makes a reference to the Observable interface. This interface does not have the method getMessage(), but how come that I can still call it?

Comment: @aaa: A PHP type-hint ensures that the argument will _at least_ implement the hinted contract, but it can implement a lot more. You can hint for an abstract class, and all child classes will be accepted, too. Basically: PHP isn't as strict as Java is. Your View class can safely assume all interface methods exist, but it's free to add `if ($argument instanceof Model) { $argument->nonInterfaceMethod(); }` You can't restrict access to public methods based on a type-hint in PHP. You'll have to use a wrapper for that, or simply refrain from calling other methods

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll accept it is as the answer because for me it is. I wanted to know how to limited the access to the model inside the view.